# Mobile Devices get HTTP 504 Error

Tags: iphone, http, blackberry, embedded

I am trying to debug why a mobile device trying to connect to my embedded web server is getting a "HTTP 504 Error: Gateway timeout".  A PC can connect just fine, it's just the Blackberries and mobile phones that get this error.

What does a 504 error mean?
What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP [status code 504](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) means that your webserver got a timeout. This message might be caused because of a slow router/gateway of your service provider, but it is also possible that your embedded webserver reacts to slow for your phones (or vice versa, even though this is very unlikely).

You might want to try connecting with your phone(s) to your webserver using a wlan-connection instead of 3G to see if this problem consist.

Sort of EDIT:
You might consider implementing debugging output to your webserver. Also it could be useful to make the timeout-parameters configurable.

Answer (score 0):

No, 504 doesn't mean that your webserver timed out.  It means that an intermediate proxy timed out while waiting for the origin server to complete the request.  "The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI." (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.5) It most likely indicates that the origin server is having some sort of issue, so it's not responding quickly to the forwarded request.

Possible solutions:

- Find out what proxy is used to handle Blackberry requests; increase its timeout value.
- Check to see if the proxy is altering your request in any way; since a PC can connect, it may be that the request is being altered.
- Make your request differently (if possible) such that you are requesting less data at a time